# select sales_order_item

Tags: magento-1, query, select

Hi i want to select a sales_order_item by order_id

```
$collection=$this->orderCollection;
       $collection->getSelect()
        ->join( array('order_item'=> 'sales_order_item'),
                'order_item.order_id = main_table.entity_id'
             )
        ->where('order_item.order_id = ' . $orderId)
        ->limit(1); $element = $this->orderCollection->getItems();
        return $element;
```

but i get only the sales_order table content

Comment: have you need only particulate order items ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chnage your code

```
$collection=$this->orderCollection;
       $collection->getSelect()
        ->join( array('order_item'=> 'sales_order_item'),
                'order_item.order_id = main_table.entity_id'
             )
        ->where('order_item.order_id = ' . $orderId)
        ->limit(1);

    //$element = $this->orderCollection->getItems();

        return $collection->getItems();
```

Comment: Updated code try with it

Comment: thx for your support i have the same  result

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    $collection  = $this->orderCollection;
    $collection->getSelect()
            ->join( array('order_item'=> 'sales_flat_order_item'),
                'order_item.order_id = main_table.entity_id'
             )
        ->where('order_item.order_id = ?', $orderId)
        ->limit(1); 


    return $collection;
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope you are using  order increment id (exp : 100000010).it is not order id..

So you can get it by using following code:

```
$id_order = 100000010; // you can get Order #  in sales order grid
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($id_order);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I got your question write, but you don't need to manually join the table, Magento can do it for you. Try the following:

```
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderId);
foreach ($order->getAllItems() as $item) {
    // Do something with your order item(s)
}
```